# How to use urllib parse_qs to construct URL

Tags: json, curl, python-requests

I've an application which returns back JSON file  like this.

```
{
  "myEvent": "Event",
  "Test": 1,
  "data": {
    "records": [
        {
            "PKID": [
                {
                    "key": "MyId1",
                    "value": "mysweetABC#1-20281231-1540#1-20281231-1540"
                },
                {
                    "key": "MyId2",
                    "value": "21623737472258061"
                }
            ],
            "ID2": [
                {
                    "key": "MyId3",
                    "value": "someclient1234"
                },
                {
                    "key": "clientOrderId",
                    "value": "1-20240220-1540"
                },
                {
                    "key": "clientFillId",
                    "value": "1-20240220-1540"
                },
                {
                    "key": "datafile",
                    "value": "DEV_TEST_CS_20240220154029.csv"
                }
            ],
```

Using the JSON, I need to construct an URL with "PKID" and send it to a 3rd party server.
I use curl for this.

My request URL should look like this

```
https://123456.abc.com/non-prod/v12-0/api/direct/7/blotter/portfolio-transactions?PKID=MyId1%3Asomeclient1234%231-20281231-1540%231-20281231-1540
```

I want to send the value of MyId1 from the above mentioned JSON file as a request payload to my URL. What I have now is

url = "https://123456.abc.com/non-prod/v12-0/api/direct/7/blotter/portfolio-transactions"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headersAuth, params=params_dict)

What should I include in params_dict here?